# How to add condition inside the array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have a nested array of objects in which I need to add condition and remove objects.

```
     const Items = [
    {
      A: 'title',
      B: [],
      C: [
        { item1: item1},
        { item2: item2 },
        { 'item3': item3},
        { 'item4': item4},
      ],
      D: 'some value',
    },
  ]
```

if my variable test is true i need below output else same as above

```
  const test  = true;// not always true
  then I need my output as  

    const Items = [
    {
      A: 'title',
      B: [],
      C: [
        { item1: item1},
        { item2: item2 },
      ],
      D: 'some value',
    },
  ]
```

{ 'item3': item3},{ 'item4': item4}, should be removed

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: @mykaf tried adding this twice using the ternary operator so want to optimize in better way
i didn't add any tried one
 test?items: newitems

Comment: Please include your attempts and we can help debug specific questions or stumbling points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary for that :

```
const test  = true;

    const Items = [
    {
      A: 'title',
      B: [],
      C: test? [
        { item1: "item1"},
        { item2: "item2" },
      ] : [
    { item1: item1},
    { item2: item2 },
    { 'item3': item3},
    { 'item4': item4},
    ],
      D: 'some value',
    },
  ]
```

Comment: i have changed your answer if you feel it is right can you approve